# How to save label control as png image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to save my label Control, but I have no idea to save it.
I tried draw text in Graphics class, but I can't draw "even allocation".
Is there any good way?

```
public Label makeLabel(string text, double width, double height, FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle fontStyle, FontStretch fontStretch)
{
    var label = new Label();
    label.Width = width;
    label.Height = height;
    label.FontFamily = fontFamily;
    label.FontStyle = fontStyle;
    label.FontStretch = fontStretch;
    label.Content = text;

    return label;
}

public void SavePicture(Label label)
{
    var path = "label.png";
    // I have no idea to save;
}
```

Comment: Why a Label, and not a TextBlock? Or even more lightweight, FormattedText in a DrawingVisual? Is it just creating a bitmap with text?

Comment: because, I only know Label what create text. I want create bitmap that have width, height, font family, font style, font stretch, and text content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public void SavePicture(Label label)
{
    var path = "label.png";

    var width = label.Width;
    var height = label.Height;

    var viewBox = new Viewbox();
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    var pngBitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

    viewBox.Child = label;
    viewBox.Measure(new Size(width, height));
    viewBox.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    viewBox.UpdateLayout();

    renderTargetBitmap.Render(viewBox);

    pngBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

    using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
    {
        pngBitmapEncoder.Save(fileStream);
    }
}
```

This works without having label displayed on screen.

Answer (score -1):

```
void SavePicture(FrameworkElement el)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)el.ActualWidth, (int)el.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(el);
    using (FileStream stream = File.Create(@"label.png"))
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

But you can call this method only after the Label is displayed.

Comment: I tried this code, but this code make transparent image.I make label in constructor, and save method do after grid loaded event.

Comment: set the Label Background in `makeLabel` method: `label.Background = Brushes.White;`